# Adding tabs to JTabbedPane causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 when tabs take a long time to load

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception, jtabbedpane

I have the following SSCCE, which takes a `JTabbedPane`, and adds 500 tabs containing a `CustomJPanel` to it. Note that the component, `CustomJPanel`, is "long" to generate, because I (purposely) add 100 `JLabel`s to it.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Parent frame");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(1200, 800);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        window.setVisible(true);

        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        window.add(jtp);

        //new Thread(new Runnable() {
        //  public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {

                    jtp.addTab("tab"+i, new CustomJPanel());
                }
        //  }
        //}).start();

    }
}

class CustomJPanel extends JPanel {

    public CustomJPanel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            this.add(new JLabel("test"));
        }
    }

}
```

When I run this code, I have a high chance to get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.tabForCoordinate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.access$2100(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The problem is caused when I quickly add components in a `JTabbedPane` that take a long time to generate. If I remove the for loop in `CustomJPanel` such that it only holds one `JLabel`, the exception doesn't happen. Note that, although in this example the exception is always "0", in my app it can be any number.

The exception seems to happen with a higher probability if the tabs are added in a separate thread.

The only way I found to reduce the probability of getting this exception is to add a delay (with `Thread.Sleep()`) of a few dozen ms between adding each tab. However, it still happens from time to time.

Is there any way to prevent this exception from occuring, or to prevent it from displaying in the console? Note that I can't catch it, because it doesn't point to anything in my code, it's all "unknown source".

**Edit:** I have changed the code of `Class1` to run on the EDT:

```
public class Class1 {
    public static JFrame window;
    public static JTabbedPane jtp;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                window = new JFrame();
                window.setTitle("Parent frame");
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setSize(1200, 800);
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                window.setVisible(true);

                jtp = new JTabbedPane();
                window.add(jtp);

                new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void doInBackground() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                            jtp.addTab("tab"+i, new CustomJPanel());

                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void done() {}

                }.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, the exception still happens. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You must only modify the UI in the Swing Event Dispatching Thread (EDT).  You cannot - must not - modify the UI in any other thread.  You can use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to switch into the EDT from a user thread.

Comment: This includes your `main()` function. It should switch to the EDT when it creates the UI.  As an exception, if the last thing the main thread does is `window.setVisible(true)`, it can USUALLY get away without the EDT switch.  But after `window.setVisible(true)`, any further UI manipulation must be done exclusively in the EDT.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the `EDT` and why the above suggestions are important.

Comment: I've followed Oracle's tutorial and modified code to run on the EDT (see edit), however the exception still happens. If I run the `for` loop for adding tabs in another `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, it seems to work but does not update the UI until all the tabs are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `doInBackground()` incorrectly.  When you are "in the background" you are not on the EDT.  So calling `addTab()`, which modifies the UI, is verboten.

To use the `SwingWorker` properly, you must `publish()` the intermediate results.  The `process()` method receives the published results in the EDT context, where it can safely modify the UI.

```
public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Class1::new);
    }

    Class1() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Parent frame");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(1200, 800);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        window.add(jtp);

        window.setVisible(true);

        new Builder(jtp).execute();
    }
}

class Builder extends SwingWorker<Void, CustomJPanel> {
    JTabbedPane jtp;

    Builder(JTabbedPane _jtp) {
        jtp = _jtp;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            CustomJPanel panel = new CustomJPanel();
            publish(panel);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<CustomJPanel> panels) {
        int i = jtp.getTabCount();
        for (CustomJPanel panel : panels) {
            jtp.addTab("tab" + i, panel);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Creating the `CustomJPanel extends JPanel` might look like you are manipulating the UI, but actually you are not.  The `JPanel` is not yet realized.  Only when the `JPanel` is added to a realized UI item, like the `JTabbedPane`, will it actually be realized.  So we can actually safely create the `JPanel`, complete with the `JLabel` children etc. in the worker thread.  But it cannot be added to the realized UI items in the worker thread.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. However I now realize that, in my app, I was kinda already doing what you are doing now: basically generating all the components before adding them all (instead of generating them on the fly each time I added a tab). I guess the problem was that I didn't use the EDT.

Comment: To be clear, creating the `JLabel` and `JPanel` in a non-UI thread is fine.  Adding the `JLabel` to the `JPanel` in a non-UI thread is also fine, because the `JPanel` doesn't exist in the display hierarchy.  The issue is doing **anything** to `JTabbedPane`, which is in the display hierarchy, from anything other than the EDT.  My `SwingWorker` is generating and adding the tabs on the fly.  But it is generating the `JPanel` and all child labels in the `SwingWorker` thread; the `JTabbedPane.addTab()` calls are done in the `EDT`.

Comment: Oh, and `process(List<CustomJPanel> panels)` is not being called once with a list of 500 panels.  It gets called multiple times with batches of panels.  The worker creates & publishes a panel.  The worker takes the published panel, creates a list of one element, and calls something like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater( list -> worker.process(list))`.  In parallel, the EDT takes the list and creates the tab, while simultaneously the background thread creates (say) 5 more panels.  These new 5 panels are passed in a new list as the next batch while the background thread creates still more panels.